# Domain Driven Design implement aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I have read about creating and responsibilities of aggregates and I have doubts how to correctly implement them. Assume that we have context within there are 2 entities. One is a Company and the second one is a User. Business rules are in the Company entity that means this should become aggregate root. To the Company we can assign ony 3 users and we can not assign User when Comapny has status "blocked". User has also possibility to login using emial and password. With that in mind every action on User entity should bo invoked thru the Aggregate root and User should not have it's own Repository. How to make login action on User when we can not do it directly without Company root? We can not call User out of the aggregate. How to find User with provided email and password? Fetching all Aggregates and iterating over their Users is inefficient and I think it's not a good idea.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Feels like you have 2 BC here. One is IdentityContext which manages credentials and another is CompanyManagementContext. About authorization. Its a tricky part whether it can be a part of IdentityContext. You should analyze how coupled authorization rules to CompanyManagementContext. Maybe it should live in CompanyManagementContext.

Answer (score 3):

I think that user should belong to another BC (that manages authentication and authorization). In your Company BC, you have to get the user from the authentication and authorization BC. You have to integrate both BCs with a context mapping pattern, where authentication and authorization BC is upstream, and Company BC is downstream.

Comment: I have put Company and User to common BC (Identity) because both Entities are strongly connected. During registration process I create Company with User(owner) therefore the best solution was to create factory method in Company aggregate to avoid inconsistency. If Company and User will be separate BC then should I throw business event and handle it in User BC?

Comment: My answer is similar to @Tseng. In Company BC (C-BC) you should have Owner and Employees. In authentication and authorization BC (AA-BC) you have Users and Roles. The context mapping is up to you. You could implement it with an async approach (events) or sync (rest api in the AA-BC). As Tseng said, from the C-BC point of view, the authentication and authorization management is infraestructure. It is an interface in the app service, implemented in the infraestructure, and in this implementation talks to AA-BC.

Comment: Thank you for help. Appreciate

Comment: I have modeled 2 BC as you suggested but I still wondering how to model communication between BC. For example Registration is a process which touch both contexts. There is one REST request - api/registration/company which cover 2 business actions. One is to cause create method on CompanyAggregate in C-BC context. After that I can fire event which will be handled in AA-BC to create user with  provide email and password. What if there will be app crash after fire first event? There will be inconsistency. Maybe registration should be simple crud operation because there is no business logic here

Comment: Communication is the other way , AA-BC is upstream , and C-BC is downstream. If you integrate both with events, the upstream publish the events and downstream listen to events. AA-BC manages users, roles, passwords, authentication, etc. It's what Vaughn Vernon says "identity and access context". Take a look at his book "Implementing domain driven design". The code is at https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples

Comment: Ok, so even if we change direction of the relationship and newly created user will throw domain event - what is next? I will try to create company and this operation fail? I know that I can call C-BC synchronous and if C-BC do not respond I will return error of creating Company(account) but this scenario tightly couple 2 BC. If there is a few BC that listen on some domain event how to detect that some of them did not complete his work or even was unavailable. It's very important when I throw domain event that VIP has been created and some bounded context did't grant rebate.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication usually isn't part of a domain (in 99% of all use cases), just part of the infrastructure.

As such `Users` shouldn't ever appear within a bounded context. In the real business world, there are no users neither, only People, Persons, Employees, Managers or Contacts etc.

So for logging concerns you have our users with username + password which serve as authentication. These users have an id (numerical, string or guid).

Your `Employee` or `Persons` entity/aggregate (or what ever you named it depends on your domain, the exact term depends from company to company - the ubiquitous language) then only contains the data which belongs to the person (but not identificaton related information).

You can then connect employees to users (either by having the employee id be the id of the users used for login, an extra field or via a 1:1 or 1:n lookup table.

This way you can easily delete a user (the login) without deleting the `Employee` entity, because in real world scenarios you can't easily just delete business data (i.e. imagine deleting a user removes the recipient on every invoice or CRM data, no one would ever know this person worked there in the past).

Comment: Thank you, I agree that in domain there is no space to word "User" :) there is CompanyOwner and Employee. So when I create company and add CompanyOwner then login mechanism should be modeled as a infrastructure service? How to connect matching result with domain Entity (Employee, CompanyOwner)?

Comment: Well easiest way is that they both use the same randomly generated id. Guids are a good match for that, since they are globally unique. The authentication happens in your application layer (the api accepting the call), after the user passes the authentication, you go on and call the domain services passing the id to the domain services/aggregates. Alternatively have an `Emplyoee`'s id saved in the Authentication user model to associate the (this way the domain is kept out of authentication and infrastructure concerns)